# How to retrieve Firebase Firestore documents between 2 dates stored as timestamps with FlutterFire plugins

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-firestore

I'd like to retrieve all orders paid between two dates:

```
    var snapshot = await db
        .collection('order')
        .orderBy('fullyPaidAt')
        .where('fullyPaidAt',
            isGreaterThan: Timestamp.fromDate(period.startsAt))
        .where('fullyPaidAt', isLessThan: Timestamp.fromDate(period.endsAt))
        .limit(10)
        .get();
```

However, I am getting results only if I use one of the where clauses. But I receive no results if I combine the 2 clauses. Is it one limitation of Firebase Firestore?

I am storing the dates in the order collection as timestamps.

See the screenshot below
[image: Imgur]

period.startsAt and period.endsAt are Dart Datetime

Answer (score 1):

**Edit:**

The problem wasn't the lack of index, but the fact that were no documents in between the `period.startsAt` and `period.endsAt`. After adding the documents with the correct date, the problem disappeared.

---

> I am storing the dates in the order collection as timestamps.

If you are storing the dates as Timestamp objects, then:

> I am getting results only if I use one of the where clauses. But I receive no results if I combine the 2 clauses.

Provides the expected behavior since such a query requires an [index](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/indexing). There's no way you can perform such a query without it.

> Is it one limitation of Firebase Firestore?

No, that's a feature that can help you perform very fast queries. That being said, you can create the required index manually directly in the [Firebase Console](https://console.firebase.google.com/u/0/) or you'll find in your IDE a message that sounds like this:

```
FAILED_PRECONDITION: The query requires an index. You can create it here: ...
```

You can simply click on that link or you can copy the URL and paste it into a web browser and your index will be created automatically for you.

Comment: I thought I don't need to create the index since single indexes are created automatically for each field. Therefore, because I am using only one single field ('fullyPaidAt'), I don't need to create manually an index. Am I correct?  Let me also clarify that I am using the timestamp type for the fullyPaid field.

Comment: Oh yes, you're right. I thought I've seen the orderBy call on a different field. In this case, please edit your question and add your database structure as a screenshot and show what does period.startsAt and period.endsAt return.

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to respond.

Comment: Then are you sure that you have documents with a date that lies in between?

Comment: You're right. To my dismay and shame, there is no document for that period. I upload the missing documents. The query was properly. Sorry for wasting your time.

Comment: I just updated my answer.